How to Select all Columns from a Table for a Record - but to exclude a Column if all entries for that Record in said Column are null?
I have a schema in a read-only Oracle database called MAXSCHEMA and a table in it called WORKORDER. This table has a column called WONUM.
If I use this SQL statement:
SELECT *
FROM MAXSCHEMA.WORKORDER
WHERE WONUM = '101319066'

I get the following 3 rows as result:



WONUM
PARENT
FAILDATE
STATUS




101319066
null
null
CLOSE


101319066
101319063
null
CAN


101319066
null
null
CLOSE



I'd like to exclude the FAILDATE column, as all entries for that WONUM record are null in that column.
In contrast, I'd like to keep the PARENT column as there is at least 1 non-null value in that column.
So my desired result would be:



WONUM
PARENT
STATUS




101319066
null
CLOSE


101319066
101319063
CAN


101319066
null
CLOSE



I understand that I can just overtly state the columns that I want:
SELECT WONUM, PARENT, STATUS
FROM MAXSCHEMA.WORKORDER

but is there any other way to exclude the FAILDATE column based on the fact that all entries for that WONUM value are null?

Simple answer: Your idea doesn't make sense and is not possible. The purpose of SQL is to provide the list of columns the result should include and then do something with this result, not vice versa.

Since you cannot drop the column from the query at run time, one option is to check if the column has any not Null values and if not then exclude the column. How many columns are there in this table and how many times you will run this query, if it is many times then you can dynamically create the query to include only Not null columns.

Once you have specified '*' in your query, it is going to return all the columns from the table no matter what their values are, including null values. So there is no workaround for that, other than explicitly removing the column from the query.
